# Responsive Image resize issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

not sure why header image is not resizing properly.  See http://www.insidemarketblog.com

I thought I set it up correctly, but the header image won't resize for mobile device.  Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
#thesis_header_image {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container_header_image {
    width: 400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="container_header_image">
<div class="text_box">
<a href="http://www.insidemarketblog.com">
<img id="thesis_header_image" width="400" height="87" src="http://www.insidemarketblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo_header1.png" alt="Inside Market Strategy header image" title="click to return home">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code at the bottom of css.css

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    #wrap{
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

This will set wrap with to auto on mobile which otherwise will stay 860px.

Comment: Nice solution, although I would choose a value of 400 or more. Most mobile devices have that resolution, and besides, the header image is 400px, so it makes sense to resize it as soon as the window is smaller than that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove width and height from the HTML. <s>HTML has precedence over anything you define in your CSS.</s>

**Edit:**

This is a fluid solution.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container-header-image">
        <a href="http://www.insidemarketblog.com">
        <img id="header-image" src="http://www.insidemarketblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo_header1.png" alt="Inside Market Strategy header image" title="click to return home">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap{
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}

.container-header-image{
    max-width: 400px;
}

#header-image {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dustindowell/W78b3/

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. Also, the 'SEO' image in the article has width and height as well. And your statement is not true. Inline *style attributes* have precedence over styles you define in CSS. In this case, the width and height attributes are specified, which is quite common for `img` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should change width of container. You don't even need `media` query.

```
#thesis_header_image {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container_header_image {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Please check [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lxfq/1/)

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that it stretches the image to 100% of 860px, and I want the image to initially be 400 width.  I implemented this change, and u can see the result.

Comment: @user3117275 updated the answer. Check now. I did that image scale to full size. but reverted it.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your css to this

```
media="screen, projection"
@media screen and (max-width: 400px)
#wrap, .container_header_image {
width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these styles

```
media="screen, projection"
@media (max-width: 450px)
.header {
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0; 

#wrap {
   width: 100%;
}

.container_header_image {
   width: 100%;
}

#thesis_header_image {
width: 100% !important;
max-width: 400px;
height: auto;
}

}
```